# QCompleter in QLineEdit has no useable height and not showing matches

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit, qcompleter

First time I'm trying to use a `QCompleter` in PyQt5.

My data is a list of dictionary objects with two text fields. I'm using a subclassed `QAbstractTableModel` to return a combined string in column 0. I'm giving this to a `QCompleter` in a `QLineEdit`. But when I try to complete, it gives me an empty popup. When I press up/down, it does go through the options (I have checked using `print()` statements in the `data()` method of my `QAbstractTableModel`) but only occasionally does it put a completed string in the text of the `QLineEdit`.
[image]

Note the popup stays empty, even when it puts a completed string in the text.
[image]

I want a "normal" popup list, like all the examples I can find online show. What am I doing wrong?

```
allSubjects = []

def loadAllSubjects():
    global allSubjects
    allSubjects = []

    cur.execute('''
        select trim(sub_code), trim(sub_desc)
        from subtab
        where cmpy_code='01' and active_flg='Y'
        order by sub_desc, sub_code
    ''')
    row = cur.fetchone()
    while row:
        (sub_code, sub_desc) = row
        allSubjects.append({
            "code": sub_code,
            "desc": sub_desc,
        })
        row = cur.fetchone()


class SubjectTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubjectTableModel, self).__init__()
    
    def rowCount(self, index) -> int:
        global allSubjects
        return len(allSubjects)
    
    def columnCount(self, index) -> int:
        return 4

    def data(self, index, role):
        # print(f"data({index.row()},{index.column()})")
        global allSubjects
        sub = allSubjects[index.row()]
        # print(sub)
        colidx = index.column()
        if colidx == 0:
            return sub["desc"] + " (" + sub["code"] + ")"
        elif colidx == 1:
            return sub
        elif colidx == 2:
            return sub["code"]
        elif colidx == 3:
            return sub["desc"]
            
    def headerData(self, colidx, orientation, role):
        if colidx == 0:
            return "Search"
        elif colidx == 1:
            return "Code"
        elif colidx == 2:
            return "Description"

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(1000, 800)

        subLabel = QLabel("Subject:")
        subSearch = QLineEdit()
        
        subCompleter = QCompleter()
        subCompleter.setModel(SubjectTableModel())
        subCompleter.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive)
        # subCompleter.setModelSorting(QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)

        subSearch.setCompleter(subCompleter)

        subPart = QHBoxLayout()
        subPart.addWidget(subLabel)
        subPart.addWidget(subSearch)

(...)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
loadAllSubjects()
app.exec()
```

**Edit:** I know it has something to do with using a `QAbstractTableModel` for my data. If I just use a list of strings instead, it works fine.

Comment: You cannot just return arbitrary values from `data()`. That's the whole purpose of [item roles](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-roles): the role is what views *ask* to the model in order to properly show items, and they expect specific data types based on those roles. You're practically returning a string even if the view is asking about a size or an icon. If you don't know or cannot provide data for a specific role, you should just return `None` (which, in Python terms, means a simple `return` statement or the end of the function). This is also valid for `headerData()` too.

Comment: Ok @musicamante thanks. How do I find out what the various roles and expected types are?

Comment: Everything is explained in the linked documentation above, and in all its related links.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit what to return based on the `role` parameter of the `data` method:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    global allSubjects
    sub = allSubjects[index.row()]
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
        colidx = index.column()
        if colidx == 0:
            return sub["desc"] + " (" + sub["code"] + ")"
        elif colidx == 1:
            return sub["code"]
        elif colidx == 2:
            return sub["desc"]
```

[Qt.DisplayRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) controls the text to show up in the popup, while [Qt.EditRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) controls the actual text inserted into the line edit.

[image: result]